# Selecting records that have duplicates on certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:-

```
LogID     Tstamp                   eCode   eOrder
14281889  2019-01-04 08:14:52.000  120     0
14281890  2019-01-04 08:14:52.000  120     0
14281891  2019-01-04 08:14:52.000  132     2
14281892  2019-01-04 08:14:52.000  133     3
14281893  2019-01-04 08:14:52.000  10      4
14281894  2019-01-04 08:15:02.000  70      0
```

I need to select the records that are duplicated by `Tstamp`, `eCode` and `eOrder` and bring back all the records that match.

e.g. the select would return

```
LogID     Tstamp                   eCode   eOrder
14281889  2019-01-04 08:14:52.000  120     0
14281890  2019-01-04 08:14:52.000  120     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `where exists` and some test code:

```
create table #testtbl (
    LogID int,
    Tstamp datetime,
    eCode tinyint,
    eorder tinyint
);

insert into #testtbl
values 
(14281889, '2019-01-04 08:14:52.000', 120, 0),
(14281890, '2019-01-04 08:14:52.000', 120, 0),
(14281891, '2019-01-04 08:14:52.000', 132, 2),
(14281892, '2019-01-04 08:14:52.000', 133, 3),
(14281893, '2019-01-04 08:14:52.000', 10, 4),
(14281894, '2019-01-04 08:15:02.000', 70, 0);

select *
from #testtbl t
where exists (
    select *
    from #testtbl
    where Tstamp = t.Tstamp
    and eCode = t.eCode
    and eorder = t.eOrder
    and LogID <> t.LogID
);
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to use a CTE to get a count:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT LogID, TStamp, eCode, eOrder,
           COUNT(LogID) OVER (PARTITION BY TStamp, eCode, eOrder) AS DupeCount
    FROM {YourTable}) --Replace {TableName} with appropriate table name.
SELECT LogID, TStamp, eCode, eOrder
FROM CTE
WHERE DupeCount > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the dups with `exists`:

```
select * from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename tt
  where tt.Tstamp = t.Tstamp and tt.eCode = t.eCode and tt.eOrder = t.eOrder and tt.LogID <> t.LogID 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I will try them all and select the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   LogID,
   Tstamp,
   eCode,
   eOrder 
from
   XXX 
where
   Tstamp + '/' + eCode + '/' + eOrder in 
   (
      select
         Tstamp + '/' + eCode + '/' + eOrder 
      from
         XXX 
      group by
         Tstamp + '/' + eCode + '/' + eOrder 
      having
         count(*) > 1
   )
;
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally not great.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using the `WITH TIES` clause and a little fun with the `sign()` of the results.

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By sign(sum(1) over (Partition By Tstamp,eCode,eorder)-1) desc
```

**Returns**

```
LogID       Tstamp                  eCode   eorder
14281889    2019-01-04 08:14:52.000 120     0
14281890    2019-01-04 08:14:52.000 120     0
```